# Best practice: how to get related entities from one entity

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, symfony

Given two entities `Permission` and `Group` and their relation-entity `GroupPermission`, I would like to get from any `Group` object, the related `Permission`.

Here is the (simplified) description of my entities:

```
----------
Permission
----------
permissionId
name

-----
Group
-----
groupId
name

----------------
GroupPermission
----------------
groupPermissionId
groupId
permissionId
```

In addition to my three document classes (describing `Permission`, `Group` and `GroupPermission` objects), I have three repository classes (containing all the database related logic).

Ideally, I would like to be able to do **`$anyGroup->getPermissions()`**, and get all `Permission` objects directly.

Since the entity should be ignorant about its repository (and other entities repository), I do not know what is the best practice to implement a such behavior.

**EDIT:** Following @KhorneHoly answer I add some constrains:

My document classes implement the `JsonSerializable` class in order to be easily serializable to JSON.
Therefore I have the following method describing how to do it:

```
public function jsonSerialize()
{
    return array(
        'groupId' => $this->getGroupId(),
        'name' => $this->getName(),
    );
}
```

And I would like to access permissions from there to include them in the JSON.

```
public function jsonSerialize()
{
    return array(
        'groupId' => $this->getGroupId(),
        'name' => $this->getName(),
        'permissions' => $this->getPermissions()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just get them with the standard Repository functions:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->getRepository('permissions')->findBy(array('groupId' => $anyGroup->getId()));
```

If you're saving the permissions into an `ArrayCollection`, there would be another way.

```
$anyGroup->getPermissions();
```

But for this to work you need to add the permissions into the `ArrayCollection` when adding the relationship.

But since there's no way to avoid flushing the entities when adding relationships, I'd always prefer the Repository way.

Comment: I was aware of this method, but I some time need to use the same behavior directly in the document class. I have edited my question in accordance.

Comment: @fef I can't see your problem. If you're using the `json_serialize` function inside your controller, you just get the permission from the repo and add them to the array.

Comment: Since this method is used very often, I would be since not having to add them manually. 
Especially when I do something like `return new JsonResponse(array('groups' => $arrayContainingMultipleGroups))`